# How to encode binary data over 65536 bytes to websocket frame on c++

Tags: c++, websocket

My server holds jpeg-file in std::string buffer (ANSI). I need to send it to web-client on request. I tried next:

```
std::string ws_encode(std::string frame) {
    string result;
    result.resize(2);
    result[0]= 130;
    if (frame.size() <= 125) {result[1]=frame.size();}
    else if (frame.size() >= 126 && frame.size() <= 65535) {
        result.resize(4);
        result[1] = 126;
        result[2] = ( frame.size() >> 8 ) && 255;
        result[3] = ( frame.size() ) && 255;
    }
    else {
        result.resize(10);
        result[1] = 127;
        result[2] = ( frame.size() >> 56 ) && 255;
        result[3] = ( frame.size() >> 48 ) && 255;
        result[4] = ( frame.size() >> 40 ) && 255;
        result[5] = ( frame.size() >> 32 ) && 255;
        result[6] = ( frame.size() >> 24 ) && 255;
        result[7] = ( frame.size() >> 16 ) && 255;
        result[8] = ( frame.size() >>  8 ) && 255;
        result[9] = ( frame.size() ) && 255;
    }
    return result+frame;
}
```

And then:

```
string encoded_frame = ws_encode(Agents["65535"].Screen); // it's a map <string id, struct Agent>, Agent has string Screen buffer for screenshots
send(client_socket, &encoded_frame[0], encoded_frame.size(), 0);
```

But the browser closes the connection without any explanations in console. Maybe length calculation is wrong, or not all data was sent... I don't know - writing test.txt with encoded data before send looks correct.

Could anybody help me in this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up the bytes of the payload length value, you are using the `LOGICAL AND` (`&&`) operator when you should be using the `BITWISE AND` (`&`) operator instead.

Try something more like this instead:

```
std::string ws_encode(char opcode, const std::string &data)
{
    string result;
    std::string::size_type size = data.size();

    if (size <= 125)
    {
        result.resize(2+size);
        result[0] = 0x80 | opcode;
        result[1] = (char) size;
    }
    else if (size <= 65535)
    {
        result.resize(4+size);
        result[0] = 0x80 | opcode;
        result[1] = 126;
        result[2] = (size >> 8) & 0xFF;
        result[3] = (size     ) & 0xFF;
    }
    else
    {
        result.resize(10+size);
        result[0] = 0x80 | opcode;
        result[1] = 127;
        result[2] = (size >> 56) & 0xFF;
        result[3] = (size >> 48) & 0xFF;
        result[4] = (size >> 40) & 0xFF;
        result[5] = (size >> 32) & 0xFF;
        result[6] = (size >> 24) & 0xFF;
        result[7] = (size >> 16) & 0xFF;
        result[8] = (size >>  8) & 0xFF;
        result[9] = (size      ) & 0xFF;
    }

    if (size > 0)
    {
        memcpy(&result[result.size()-size], data.c_str(), size);
        // or:
        // std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), result.begin()+(result.size()-size));
    }

    return result;
}
```

```
std::string encoded_frame = ws_encode(0x02, Agents["65535"].Screen);
send(client_socket, encoded_frame.c_str(), encoded_frame.size(), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code works - browsers doesn't close the connection on message. But I still can't see an image in this src and its size is almost twice lower than source buffer (source is 90-150 kb, incoming blob ~70kb). In this regard, I want to clarify one thing - if I will send data in parts by 1kb for example, until I send the entire packet, do I have to encode each part somehow, or just encode the whole packet and transfer its parts as in regular sockets?

Comment: Either `Screen` does not contain a valid image to begin with, or you are not displaying it correctly on the browser side. Either way, that is a separate issue then the issue of encoding the WebSocket packet. `encoded_frame` is the complete WebSocket packet, so just `send()` it as-is, looping the `send()` as many times as it takes to send all of the bytes, just like with any other socket implementation, eg: `const char *ptr = encoded_frame.c_str(); int size = encoded_frame.size(); while (size > 0) { int r = send(client_socket, ptr, size, 0); if (r <= 0) break; ptr += r; size -= r; }`

Comment: The lower size of incoming package was my mistake - the client, which sends those images to server operates a single send function instead of looping send(). I add loop and all data is OK. The image is valid, I'm going to search errors in javascript logic. Thank you again!